# Can you interact with anything in the demo version of Epic Citadel?

Tags: epic-citadel

I downloaded the free Epic Citadel demo for the iPhone last night. This game is downright **gorgeous.** Who'd have thought I'd see the day when games have Oblivion-quality graphics on a phone?

But ... is there a game in here? Is there anything to do other than sightsee? Don't get me wrong, that will be entertaining for a while -- but not enough to justify 84 meg of my phone's storage being gone. :)

Is there anything you can interact with? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is strictly an (amazingly gorgeous!) tech-demo, not a full-fledged game.  It's stated a little more clearly on the [homepage](http://www.epicgames.com/technology/epic-citadel) than in the app description.

However, I would expect if they went to the effort of building this, and it only took a few weeks, they'll put out something with actual gameplay in the future.

Comment: They demoed actual gameplay, too ... Fingers crossed!

Comment: The actual gameplay is coming this holiday season according to the creative director and president of Epic during their keynote presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, like sjohnston said, it is really quite beautiful, but it's only a demo.  However, it is planned to be a part of their upcoming game code named "Project Sword" which they said would be released "this holiday season".

If you [check out the keynote on Apple's site](http://events.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1009qpeijrfn/event/index.html) you can see near the beginning of the presentation, where two guys from Epic Games come up to the stage to discuss it, and they demo the game, which looks a lot like Epic Citadel, until one of the dudes gets an invite, and they go into this super boss, awesome and epic sword battle! :D

Yeah really btw on the graphics though, they're soo awesome.

I can't wait until the final!